# Изменения метки в форме

Tags: python, django

Как можно упростить изменения метки в форме? Можно проще и в html менять, необходимо в forms.py

```
class SClientsForm(ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(SClientsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['swname'].label = "Имя"

class Meta:
    model = SClients
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, не совсем правильно понял вопрос но:
Задайте какой-нибудь метод для формы, которая будет менять лэйбл по ключу поля в атрибуте fields

```
class SClientsForm(ModelForm):  
   def change_label(field_key, label):  
       self.fields[field_key].label = label

class Meta:  
    model = SClients
```

Ну и меняйте где хотите, хоть в других методах формы, хоть в самом коде где угодно:

```
form = SClientsForm()   
form.change_label('swname', u'Новая метка')
```